# iOS Instagram image share with Cropping Page

Tags: ios, instagram-api

I want t share my image with instagram and my code goes me to Instagram Filter page.But I want to share my image firstly open instagram image cropping page, then filter page and then share it.
Is it possible to open Instagram cropiing page firstly?
Thanks

```
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0,0,0);
NSString *jpgPath=[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/test.igo"];

[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(instaImage, 1.0) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];
NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"file://%@",jpgPath]];
self.dic=[UIDocumentInteractionController  interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];
self.dic.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
[self.dic presentOpenInMenuFromRect: rect  inView: self.view animated: YES ];
```